# Python Multiprocessing (Pool) Appears to Launch Duplicate Processes of Other Program

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I am new to using multiprocessing and Pool, and I think it launches multiple processes of another software, specifically R, when my code calls Pool.

I use 16 cores, and the cores do not need to communicate.  `top` shows all Python processes launch correctly, but I noticed that R seemed to accumulate running instances.  My machine, an Ubuntu 16.04 box, does launch R every 5 minutes, and I noticed the running times of pairs of R instances were 5 minutes apart.  In other words, my computer seems to launch two instances of R in these cases. I can get rid of the R instances with `killall R`. Each R instance used ~99% of its core.

At first, I thought this problem was related to my machine, but I noticed the behavior stopped at some point after my Python script completes.  (I do not know precisely when because I did not monitor the script the whole time it runs.)  I launched the script with `nohup` and see no weird output in `nohup.out`.  The code runs on Python 2.7.

The full code is at simulations.py at this repository: https://github.com/shanest/scale-free-protest.  What I think is the relevant snippet (let me know if more detail is needed):

```
def run_experiment(out_file, scales, repression_rates,
    num_nodes=[40000], threshold=2, trials_per_setting=2500, num_procs=16):
"""Runs an experiment.  Handles the main loops for running individual
trials, as well as the recording of data to a file. Returns nothing,
but writes to out_file.

Args:
    out_file: file to write to
    scales: an iterable of possible scaling parameters
    repression_rates: an iterable of possible repression rates
    num_nodes: how many nodes to put in each graph
    threshold: the threshold to use for ProtestAgents
    trials_per_setting: how many trials to run per
                        (scale X repression_rate) setting
    num_procs: how many processes to spawn to run trials
"""
parameters = [(num, gamma, threshold, repression_rate)
        for num in num_nodes for gamma in scales
        for repression_rate in repression_rates
        for _ in xrange(trials_per_setting)]
procs = Pool(num_procs)

# send work to pool, wrapped in a progress bar
data = list(tqdm.tqdm(procs.imap(run_trial_from_tuple, parameters),
    total=len(parameters)))

# write output
head_line = ('num_nodes,gamma,threshold,repression_rate,initial_size,' +
        'initial_density,initial_clustering,final_size,num_iters')
np.savetxt(out_file, data, delimiter=',', header=head_line, comments='')
```

On one hand, all my code produces what it should.  I would like to figure out what is going on so that I do not have to worry about overtaxing my computer when I am not around to manually kill processes.

Comment: what does `run_trial_from_tuple` do?

Comment: It calls the `run_trial` function, which does the main work of the script.  It's a long function so I don't want to put it in the body of the question.  That function, and the full script, can be found at this Github repo: https://github.com/shanest/scale-free-protest.  I put the repo link in the post as well.